# Playstation 4 OpenGL ES support (or Xbox)

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, graphics-programming, cross-platform, playstation4

I know that the Playstation 3 supported at least OpenGL ES 1.0, and the Vita OpenGL ES 2.0. But what about the Playstation 4 (and/or the new PS4 Pro)? Does anyone know for certain if it has native support for OpenGL ES (that is, without using a compatibility/translation layer like ANGLE)?

Because it isn't backwards compatible with regular OpenGL, it'd be helpful to know if this platform supports any version of the OpenGL ES API.

I'm also curious about the Xbox One/Scorpio, although I'd be surprised if they had nativesupport for OpenGL at all.

Answer (score 3):

The PlayStation 4 uses proprietary graphics APIs (GNM, a low-level API, and GMNX, a higher-level one). It does not support OpenGL in any capacity, not even the limited "[PSGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSGL)" API used in the PlayStation 3, as far as I am aware.

The Xbox doesn't support OpenGL either.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Xbox support OpenGL ES via [ANGLE transition layer](https://github.com/microsoft/angle/tree/uwp-2017) which compile as UWP SDK, not Xbox XDK

PS4 support OpenGL ES as [native API](https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products/opengles#submission_556)

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thank you for contributing. There's no need to edit the information you've posted into the answers by other users, especially when in conflicts with their intent. user1430 was answering in the context of "*without* using a compatibility/translation layer like ANGLE" as posted in the question.